# Should this code-only answer be accepted

Tags: discussion, answers

While I was arguing with a user for what was in my opinion a code-only answer, he told me that it is the only answer you could give since the OP didn't provide enough information.

This is [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16822788/1063093).

Are code only answers valid in these situations?

Comment: The answer is careless, but a downvote feels way exaggerated in this case

Comment: @Pekka웃 Then where is the line between a valid and a non-valid code-only answer ? Also the downvote is because I judge he could easily explain what he changed and why he changed it.

Comment: In most cases that I see, code-only answers make too many assumptions about the user's ability to understand them. However, since the question in the case was "_But how do the where clause?_" this answer seems appropriate.

Comment: I agree the answer could easily be improved a lot, e.g. by pointing to the manual

Comment: Well the OP can accept whichever answer they want, if you don't like the answer downvote/comment and move one

Comment: Two wrongs don't make a right and you are acting childish in the comment section

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think some code-only answers are not that bad. It depends on what the question is. If, for example, someone is asking:

> how can I code such a task?

How is a code-only answer incomplete? It is as complete as an answer that only adds: "Here's the answer", "I think you need this:" or any other variant of this phrase to the code.

It is true that we might want some explanation behing the code, but, IMHO, if not specified otherwise in the question, code-only answers are *acceptable* as well.

You can always post a comment to require more out of an answer, but I think downvoting or, even worse, flagging is an exaggeration.

Comment: Flagging is not necessary, since there isn't anything a moderator can do. Moderators would not probably delete an answer just because it contains only code.

Comment: @kiamlaluno, I have seen a few *very low-quality* flags on this type of answers.